# "Error: Http failure response" error when compiling Angular SSR

Tags: angular

When opening my local website running through Angular Universal, the error is presented below but specifically starting on the "Error" line:

```
Compiled successfully.
** Angular Universal Live Development Server is listening on http://localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
Angular is running in development mode.    
http://localhost:4200/home
[2023-11-16T14:17:38.774Z][Error]: Erro: Http failure response for https://localhost:44372/api/Article/ArquivesArticlesAnoMes: 0 undefined
HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map(0) {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'https://localhost:44372/api/Article/ArquivesArticlesAnoMes',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for https://localhost:44372/api/Article/ArquivesArticlesAnoMes: 0 undefined',
  error: TypeError: fetch failed
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    cause: Error: self-signed certificate
        at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1659:34)
        at invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:402:31)
        at run (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14371:55)
        at onInvokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14371:36)
        at invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:401:60)
        at onInvokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14684:33)
        at invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:401:60)
        at runTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:173:47)
        at invokeTask (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:483:34)
        at TLSSocket.ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:472:48) {
      code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
    }
  }
}
```

Although it presents the error, my website works normally. Is this error normal? Or is there a way to correct or work around it?

version Angular:

```
Angular CLI: 17.0.1
Node: 20.9.0
Package Manager: npm 10.2.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.0.1
@angular-devkit/core            17.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.1
@angular/cdk                    17.0.0
@angular/cli                    17.0.1
@angular/material               17.0.0
@angular/ssr                    17.0.1
@schematics/angular             17.0.1
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.2.2
zone.js                         0.14.2
```

Comment: Are you using angular 17?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to include the Angular version.

Comment: I created a demo repository [here](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/DotnetAngularSSR). Would be interested in the answer as well

Comment: Thank you, but the problem still persists, I believe that compiling in local ssr in development mode is normal.
In production the problem does not occur.

Comment: I discovered that this error only happens at compile time in development mode. In production the problem does not occur, but I cannot explain why.